# Hyperlink text on top of image in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a Hyperlink text on top of the image in HTML5 .
Please suggest how to do ?

Regars,
RAvi

Comment: any example how it should look like

Comment: I think you should go with a div which have background image as the image you want to place and then write inside it....

Comment: I need to show text with hyperlinks hover on Image, I have tried with text in same div where image is there. But it doesn't wotk and i think the text is displaying behind the image.

Comment: Follow below answer, it is the same implementation as I mentioned...

Comment: why this question put on hold? I have asked a related to HTML5 questions and I got few valid answers for this also.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need `javascript` for this only `css` and `html`

```
<div id ="all"><a href="http://google.com">Click here to go</a></div>

#all{    
background:url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png') no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

[demo for this](http://jsfiddle.net/u93vY/1/)

For 4 links as you want

```
<div id ="all">
<a href="http://google.com">Click here to go1</a><br>
<a href="http://hotmail.com">Click here to go1</a><br>
<a href="http://yahoo.com">Click here to go1</a><br>
<a href="http://google.com">Click here to go1</a><br>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3rnel31/SfqZU/2/)

Comment: Yes, its great, but i need to display 4 text link on top of the image. Not only one. Can i use different div and can give id to css to display it?

Comment: @RaviKChowdary this 4 links should be Horizontal or Vertical?

Comment: same like the above vertical :) i will try with the above code once

Comment: @RaviKChowdary You never mentioned anything about 4 text links in the question, so how were we supposed to know? Be specific in the question!

Comment: @RaviKChowdary can you please turn the answer as correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an imagemap. This lets you have as many links as you want, with no CSS needed!

However, imagemaps are buggy on (some) iphones.